# 3DOF end effector control

Tags: robotics, kinematics

I have created a simple serial robot with some servos and CAD.

[image]

Each joint has 180 degrees of freedom, where they all have 180 degrees of freedom.
I haven't specified where the 180 degrees of freedom actually is practically because that range is adjustable to what is sensible, which I am not sure about.

---

I really want to be able to control the end effector with two joysticks, one for x & y axis and one for z axis. Because right now (like all other youtube videos) I can only control one servo at a time...

So I understand I'll need to use some rotation matrices and stuff to make this work but I don't know where to start!

---

The textbooks I have are quite dense mathematically and too much for just a small part of the overall project, can someone please let me know what is the easiest way to achieve this or point me in the right direction?

More than happy to have a chat outside of stack exchange if someone is willing to somewhat walk me through it.

Cheers!

Comment: So, you basically want to move all the joints of the robot using the joysticks but without involving any maths ?

Comment: Oh no I'm more than happy to use maths, I just don't know where to start! 
with anything there is a quick and dirty solution right?